# Question with 'top up for mobile'?

Tags: grammar

Is this sentence correct?

I'd like 5 pounds top up for lyca mobile, please.

Comment: What is it you are asking for? Other than that you probably want to capitalize Lyca (and maybe Mobile)  the sentence ***could*** be correct, or it might make no sense at all. It all depends on what you want it to mean.

Comment: My guess, *"I'd like to buy a 5-pound top-up card for my Lycamobile, please."* -- I wasn't sure what Lyca mobile was, though, so I searched for it and found http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lycamobile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're adding 5 pounds to your Lyca mobile account.  Sounds right to me.

Comment: -1, sentence makes *no* sense to me.

Comment: What part of it?  And where are you from?  To "top up" or "top off" something means to fill it up.  Just like a cup of coffee at a restaurant, your server can "top up your coffee".  This is a similar concept.  Just adding a little bit (5 pounds) to something (your Lyca mobile account).

Comment: America. Replacing "top up" with "top off", "I'd like 5 pounds top off for lyca mobile, please," still makes no sense. "5 pounds to top off my lyca mobile account?" best guess.

Comment: I don't know which part doesn't make sense. If I could answer that, some of it would make sense.